# FragmentStatePagerAdapter Cache usage

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

[image]When using FragmentStatePagerAdapter is an Android version of "This is better for pagination through a collection of objects for the number of pages is indeterminate. Destroy fragments as the user navigates to other pages, minimizing memory usage "
The operation of this widget to make the creation of a page before the actual position, in my case I consume different services each time I scroll over the tabs and obviously the data can be updated, since paging loads a position towards Forward when I return to the previous position does not perform service request because FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not detect this, please someone knows how to resolve this FragmentStatePagerAdapter

The length of my tabs is dynamic, that's why I'm using 2 Fragment, one for the tabs and another for the pager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand your problem, let me guess your previous or next Fragment was not destroy and when you swipe the page back to previous page or next page it does trigger Network request.

Yes, if it the case then Fragment does not remove from activity which mean not lifecycle trigger to the fragment. However if you need to trigger the network then in your FragmentStatePagerAdapter override this method [setPrimaryItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#setPrimaryItem(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object)) then send the callback to your Fragment (The object pass in should be your live instance fragment). Set primary will provide the one which being visible to the user which is actually the current item of ViewPager.

Comment: that is the problem that I have a good guess, have some example in code of this solution that I just Provide, as I do To inflate the fragment in setPrimaryItem? @vsatkh

Comment: Please check my gist sample on github https://gist.github.com/cmidt-veasna/97812e07a387bd3cca62fa73ae4070d6 I haven't test the code thought but it should work as intended.

Comment: I do not understand this part that is supposed to load here? `public void loadData() {
      // your code
    }`

Comment: Ah, isn't that you need to reload data from the server and referesh your View ? That method is just a dummy code as an example where I do write a code to reload data and I apologize that I put the comment as "your code". You can just forget about it and use your own code to reload the data.

Comment: I understand the idea, to load the data of this fragment again, but since I can reload them, the method
`@Override public Fragment getItem (int index) {` is where I can find my fragment, but I do not understand how to do it in
`@Override public void setPrimaryItem (container ViewGroup, int position, Object object) {` explain?

Comment: Maybe I leave to many choice with comment and make complicated. So basically, you don't need to do anything with your adapter, You just need to override this "setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)" in Fragment and reload the data if the isVisibleToUser is true.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo :( @vsatkh

Comment: Find this, you understand[link](http://doublenegative.com/fragment-state-restoration-and-the-fragmentstatepageradapter/)